# String Split to new Elements using XSL 1.0

Tags: xslt

Can any guide me to split the given xml element values into multiple child elements based on a token. Here is my sample input xml and desired output. I have a limitation to use xsl 1.0. Thank you.

**Input XML:**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SQLResults>
    <SQLResult>
        <ACTION1>Action1</ACTION1>
        <ACTION2>Action2</ACTION2>
        <Encrypt>Program=GPG;Code=23FCS;</Encrypt>
        <SENDER>Program=WebPost;Protocol=WS;Path=/home/Inbound</SENDER>
    </SQLResult>
</SQLResults>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<SQLResults>
    <SQLResult>
        <ACTION1>Action1</ACTION1>
        <ACTION2>Action2</ACTION2>
        <Encrypt>
            <Program>GPG</Program>
            <Code>23FCS</Code>
        </Encrypt>
        <SENDER>
            <Program>Action4</Program>
            <Protocol>WS</Protocol>
            <Path>/home/Inbound</Path>
        </SENDER>
    </SQLResult>
</SQLResults>
```

Comment: Well, first check whether your XSLT 1.0 processor does not support http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html, if not, you can still use the XSLT 1.0 template based implementation http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/str.tokenize.template.xsl.

Comment: Thank you. I am checking that. Appreciate if you can point me to a snippet with above function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `XSLT 2` it would be easy, just with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="Encrypt|SENDER">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w+)=([\w/]+);?">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <element name="{regex-group(1)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
        </element>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Because you want to do it in `XSLT 1`, you have to express it another way.

Instead of `analyze-string` you have to:

- Tokenize the content into non-empty tokens contained between `;` chars.
  You have to add `tokenize` template.
- Each such token divide into 2 substrings, before and after `=` char.
- Create an element with the name equal to the first substring.
- Write the content of this element - the second substring.

`XSLT 1` has also such limitation that the result of the `tokenize` template
is a *result tree fragment (RTF)* not the *node set* and thus it cannot be
used in `XPath` expressions.

To circumvent this limitation, you must use `exsl:node-set` function.

So the whole script looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Encrypt|SENDER">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="tokens">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="."/>
          <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="';'"/>
        </xsl:call-template> 
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($tokens)/token">
        <xsl:variable name="t1" select="substring-before(., '=')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="t2" select="substring-after(., '=')"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$t1}">
          <xsl:value-of select="$t2" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="txt" />
    <xsl:param name="delim" select="' '" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$delim and contains($txt, $delim)">
        <token>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($txt, $delim)" />
        </token>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
          <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="substring-after($txt, $delim)" />
          <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="$delim" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$txt">
        <token><xsl:value-of select="$txt" /></token>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. It's doing my job. Thank you again.